# Cannot set a global variables from a Callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm not able to set a global variable `ApiToken` from the CallBack function `processGetToken`.
Could you explain why, and post a sample of code?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // General Settings
    var ApiToken, ApiUriGetToken, ApiUriGetPlaylist,
    ApiSettings = {
        clientId: encodeURIComponent('aaa'),
        clientSecret: encodeURIComponent('bbb')
    };
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // URIs to xxx API:
    // Token
    ApiUriGetToken = 'https://api.xxx.com/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=' + ApiSettings.clientId + '&client_secret=' + ApiSettings.clientSecret;

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Asynchronous requests using Ajax

    // Get Token
    function ApiGetToken() {
        $.getJSON(ApiUriGetToken, processGetToken);
    }

    // Get Token : Callback
    function processGetToken(data) {
        ApiToken = data.access_token;   // Set the Token as Global variable
        // Update the URIs with the a Token generated
        ApiUriGetPlaylist = 'https://api.xxx.com/playlist?oauth_token=' + ApiToken + '&account=' + ApiSettings.clientId;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Get Categories
    function ApiGetPlaylist() {
        ApiGetToken();  // Get a fresh Token
        $.getJSON(ApiUriGetPlaylist, processGetCategories);
    }

    // Get Categories : Callback
    function processGetCategories(data) {
        var content = '';
        // Trasvers
        $.each(data.result, function (i, element) {
            content += element.name;
        });
        // Inject in the DOM
        $('#view01-caregories').text('ciao');

    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Testing
    ApiGetToken();
    console.log('ApiUriGetToken: ' + ApiUriGetToken);
    console.log('ApiToken: ' + ApiToken);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in connection of AJAX Asynchronous request. I placed the code in a unique callback function, resolving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the variable ApiToken inside a function, so it only exists in that function - not ouside it.  To make it global, simply declare it outside the function like this...

```
var ApiToken;

$(document).ready(function () {

    // General Settings
    var ApiUriGetToken, ApiUriGetPlaylist,
    ApiSettings = {
        clientId: encodeURIComponent('aaa'),
        clientSecret: encodeURIComponent('bbb')
    };
```

You still use it exactly the same inside the function, but it exists globally so everything else can reference it.

Comment: I have tried but still with the same problem

Comment: Please note my script is included in the html page using <script src=..>

Comment: That should work fine.  Did you notice that as well as declaring it outside the function I had also removed it from the variable declaration inside the function?

Comment: I believe my problem is that  ApiGetToken() is an asynchronous call.. I still have the problem thanks for your help on this

Comment: To solve the problem I had to use a unique ajax request, thanks for your comments